# How to create fixed, scrollable div with percentage height?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to create a fixed div in the middle of a page that is scrollable, but I'm not able to get the div to scale to the page size properly. It's set to take 70% of the page (AKA, stopping around 20px from the bottom of the browser) but when you make the height of the browser less, it doesn't seem to react properly.

I can't seem to figure out why this is, suspect it's related to fixed positioning a div and then attempting to use a percentage height but I am sure there is a way around it.

To see what I mean, there is an example website [here](http://fem.dreamhosters.com/?p=4) for this. Drag the window up from the bottom and eventually the div does not resize anymore. :(

The CSS for the div is:

```
.singlepost {
position: fixed;
height: 70%;
background-color: white;
padding-left: 10px;
padding-right: 10px;
overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

And the structure of the HTML is:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="container">
     [This is the fixed width box I want to size]
    </div>
</div>
```

One idea I had was to use javascript to determine the height of the browser dynamically and set the fixed with to a specific pixel height but I doubt that's the best way to solve this.

Comment: need javascript..you can declare element to be block element and it will expand 100% of available space width wise, but height wise there is no way to do it. and this is what people mean css was made for showing documents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your page is calculating the height of the `.singlepost` div correctly. It is always 70% and it is adjusting when the page height gets smaller.

The problem is the `.singlepost` div sits after some content that is a fixed height. So when the content above the `.singlepost` div is greater than 30% of the page height, the `.singlepost` div does not exceed the bottom of the page. But when you make the page height smaller, the top content gets less than 30% of the page, and at that point the bottom of the `.singlepost` div will drop under the bottom of the page.

Rather than setting the height, you can set the top and bottom:

**CSS**

```css
.singlepost {
    position: fixed;
    background-color: white;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-right: 10px;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    top: 270px;
    bottom: 20px;
}
```

This assumes that your top content is 270px high.

Comment: Wow, that's awesome and makes complete sense now that you say it. Thanks so much for the explanatory and helpful answer! :)